# mongoid self to self relationship?

Tags: ruby, mongoid, web-crawler

Hi guys I have a class like below for a crawler model:

```
class Link
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :url, type: String
  field :links, type: String
  index :url
  has_many :pages
end
```

where a link repent a URL and they have many inbound/outbound connections, I would like to have it working, so:

```
a_link.links  # => gives a list of outbound link objects.
```

How would you do it with mongoid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set up a many-many association using `has_and_belongs_to_many` on each side of the relationship.

```
class Link
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :links, :class_name => 'Link', :inverse_of => :inbound_links
  has_and_belongs_to_many :inbound_links, :class_name => 'Link', :inverse_of => :links
end
```

As the association is to and from the same class in this case you need to give mongoid a little help with the class_name and inverse_of because it can't infer this from the association name.

Answer (score 2):

a bit cleaner way to archive this using many-many associations

```
class Link
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :links, class_name: 'Link', inverse_of: :links
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add the reference of links to the document on the other end. (See an example conversation here: https://github.com/openfarmcc/OpenFarm/pull/924#pullrequestreview-33231415)